# Bing Entities Search not available outside US

Tags: bing, entities

I have tried this code [Tutorial: Single-page web app source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-entities-search/tutorial-bing-entities-search-single-page-app-source)

I need to find a local business data via this API

everything found if i search something on US, but not on other countries

Is it not supported on others countries then US? How to make the search supported for other countries?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the market (**mkt**) parameter. Check out supported market codes and mkt parameter definition here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-entities-api-v7-reference.

Comment: I did, on that sample we can choose the market on the right side bar. still no result...

Comment: which market value you are using? Can you provide your URL call here?

Comment: the api call like [https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/entities?q=pizza&mkt=de-DE&SafeSearch=off](https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/entities?q=pizza&mkt=de-DE&SafeSearch=off) .... thanks for the respond

Answer (score 0):

Bing Entity Search API returns "Entities" and "Places". "Entities" information is available for [multiple markets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-entities-api-v7-reference#market-codes). "Places" information, as of now is available for only US market. This is mentioned in the section "showcase of local businesses nearby" on the [Entity API page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-entity-search-api/).